# React Navigation: Prevent multiple instances to navigate to same screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Let's say I have this screen:

[image: screenshot]

And when the user clicks on the white tooltip, it redirects to another screen. Sometimes the app lags a little bit, and clicking on the tooltip takes like ~2s to see the screen change. The problem is, during those 2s, the user *taps again* on this tooltip to make it happen.

And the result I get is that there are two instances of the new screen in my StackNavigator. What I mean is that I see my new screen, but when I click on "Back" I don't return to this 'Hitchhiking Map' screen, but to another instance of that same screen.

If I clicked 5 times on the callout during those 2s, then I need to click 5 times "Back" to return to the Map screen. Any way to prevent that? To put only one instance into the StackNavigator?

I am using React Navigation, more precisely a StackNavigator. Here's my code:

The "click on tooltip" part:

```
<MapView.Marker
  onCalloutPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('spotDetails', { spotId: marker.id })}
/>
```

My screens:

```
const HMapNavigator = StackNavigator({
  HMap: { screen: HMapViewContainer },
  spotDetails: { screen: SpotDetailsViewContainer },
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue of multiple navigations has been reported and there is more detail [here](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/271).

react-navigation (v1.0.0-beta.7) is in beta and still being built, so until this feature is implemented, you will have to handle the debounce manually.

**options**

- disable the button once the navigation starts
- debouncing in the `onPress` logic or in the action if you are using redux

[lodash](https://lodash.com) provides a useful debounce utility, if you are looking for one.

Comment: Hi Stewart, can you please show an example of how to do this with lodash debounce ?

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways how to overcome double navigations.

My solution is adding a `key` property in navigate object:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate({ key: 'AnotherScreen', routeName: 'AnotherScreen', params: { ... }})}
```

Comment: What happens when you add key property? how it solves ?

Comment: I do not know how it is working under the hood. I have just read it in issues as a possible workaround. It is enough for me for now.

Comment: @matusalem thanks for the solution.How it works under hood can be understood from the api of the navigate method.The key is the identifier for the route to navigate to.If similar key is present than it will Navigate back to the same  route.
api ref:https://reactnavigation.org/docs/1.x/navigation-actions#navigate

Answer (score 0):

Save if its opening to control the navigation

```
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      opening: false
    }
  }
```

Create a function to control de navigation

```
  _open (campaign) {
    if (!this.state.opening) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Campaign', {campaign})
      this.setState({ opening: true })
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ opening: false })
      }, 1000)
    }
  }
```

Call this func from your `onpress`

```
<TouchableHighlight underlayColor='transparent' onPress={this._open.bind(this, campaign)}>
```

Answer (score 0):

In versions **1.x** of React Navigation, if you specify an identifier the navigation action will be executed only once. E.g.:

```
navigate({ routeName: 'someScreen', key: 'someScreen', params: { someParam: 'someValue' } })
```

More information: https://gist.github.com/vonovak/ef72f5efe1d36742de8968ff6a708985

In versions **2.x** and **3.x** this is a default functionality.

More info: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-key.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hook that prevents navigating when the screen is not in focus. `useIsFocused` comes from `react-navigation`

```
export const useRootNavigation = (): NavigationProp<RootStackParamList> & PushFunction => {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();
  const navigation = useNavigation<NavigationProp<RootStackParamList> & PushFunction>();
  const push = useCallback<PushFunction['push']>(
    (...args) => {
      if (isFocused) {
        navigation.push(...args);
      }
    },
    [navigation, isFocused],
  );
  return { ...navigation, push };
};
```